# C# vs SQLEditor -- Npgsql.PostgresException 42703: column "username" does not exist

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, npgsql

So on my behind code in C# I have a Select Statement:

```
Select username from vw_members where username = 'SomeValue'
```

But that returns this error on my aspx page:column "username" does not exist

If I run that same statement in the pgAdmin SQLEditor it runs no problem

If I run something like this on my behind code:

```
Select username from tbl_users where username = 'SomeValue'
```

Runs fine.

The view is a join with the user table and a members table.
here is my C# code:

```
string selectstmt = "Select UserName from vw_members where UserName = 'SomeValue'";
```

My View in pgAdmin looks like:

```
SELECT tbl_member.usertype AS "usertype",
    tbl_member.userid AS "userid",
    tbl_member.createdate AS "createdate",
    tbl_member.lastlogindate AS "lastlogindate",
    tbl_member.email AS "email",
    tbl_users.userid AS "usersid",
    tbl_users.username AS "username",
    tbl_users.lastactivitydate AS "lastactivitydate"
   FROM tbl_users,
    tbl_member
  WHERE tbl_users.userid = tbl_member.userid;
```

Comment: Are you using the correct database? Perhaps the user that you are logging into SQLEditor has a different default database than the user that you're using to connect in c#?

Comment: I checked this scenario, both are using the same database, as well as the same user.--Thank you

Comment: If it possible that you have case sensitive column collation enabled? I noticed that you use `username` in one example, but `Username` in the other.

Comment: It is on, and by correcting my queries case on the columns solved my problem. -- Thank you!

Comment: Excellent! Glad to hear you've got a solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was suggested I have a look to see if ***case sensitive column collation was enabled*** and turns out it is enabled. From there I made sure all  my column names match in the same case, after that everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an explicit join in your view:

```
SELECT tbl_member.usertype AS "usertype",
    tbl_member.userid AS "userid",
    tbl_member.createdate AS "createdate",
    tbl_member.lastlogindate AS "lastlogindate",
    tbl_member.email AS "email",
    tbl_users.userid AS "usersid",
    tbl_users.username AS "username",
    tbl_users.lastactivitydate AS "lastactivitydate"
FROM tbl_users LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_member
    ON tbl_users.userid = tbl_member.userid
```

May not make any difference, but it is something to try.